# How to make Font Awesome icon clickable to open a modal in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
```

this is the sample icon that i want to click to open a modal.
required:
1.bootstrap 3 (since the previous Template Design using bootstrap 3)

Comment: Just wrap it in an element with `data-toggle` and `data-target` on it, as per the [documentation](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#my-modal)

Comment: Simply do `<i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></i>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this could help:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i>



  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```